# Hole or Edge or gap

Tags: word-request

What do you call the small holes in a rock? I mean the holes the rock climbers put their fingers while climbing a rock.

Do you call it, a hole or edge or gap or something else?

Comment: a crack, a crevice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I thought it was what CopperKettle said, a crack or a crevice then I did a little research on Google and came up with the correct term, pocket.  According to [an about.com article](http://climbing.about.com/od/RockClimbingTechnique/tp/Nine-Basic-Types-Of-Climbing-Handholds.htm), it's one of nine basic types of climbing handholds.